# having trouble with partitioning the harddisk

Tags: 14.04, fdisk

While I use the command `fdisk /dev/sdb1` the following error happens.

```
fdisk: unable to read /dev/sdb1: Inappropriate ioctl for devic
```

Comment: First off, you shouldn't be partitioning /dev/sdb1. /dev/sdb1 is the first partition on /dev/sdb. So, you should instead use /dev/sdb. Are there any partitions currently on the drive? If not, that'd be the reason for the ioctl error.

Comment: Try running gparted as a nice graphical tool, might help also!

Comment: @Githlar: Your comment should be an answer to this question.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using the device /dev/sdb NOT /dev/sdb1 (which would be a partition, you can't partition a partition).